# Foreach works for children with JSON but not with ViewModel

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am successfully binding hierarchical JSON data to my view. But the foreach function does not iterate through child arrays once I project that same JSON data into a viewmodel using knockout.mapping.

When binding to the viewModel data, I know the child data (Answers) is there because I can display the object references using

The views:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: $data">
    <p data-bind="html: QuestionText">

    <!-- this section outputs [object Object] when bound to pageViewModel or Json -->
    <p data-bind="html: Answers">

        <!-- RadioButtonSelection-->
        <div data-bind="if: QuestionSelectionMode == 'RadioButtonSelection'">
            <span data-bind="foreach: $data.Answers">
                <input type="radio" data-bind="attr: {name: $parent.QuestionId}, value: AnswerId" /><span data-bind="text: AnswerText"></span>
            </span>
        </div>

        <!-- CheckBoxSelection-->
        <div data-bind="if: QuestionSelectionMode == 'CheckBoxSelection'">
            <span data-bind="foreach: $data.Answers">
                <div><input type="checkbox" data-bind="value: AnswerId"/><span data-bind="text: AnswerText"></span></div>
            </span>
        </div>

        <!-- DropDownListSelection-->
        <div data-bind="if: QuestionSelectionMode == 'DropDownListSelection'">
            <select data-bind="options: $data.Answers, optionsText: 'AnswerText', optionsValue: 'AnswerId'"></select>
        </div>

    </p>
</div>
```

The ViewModel code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    /* get the first page of questions and bind them */
    @{ 

        string startUrl = "URL-Removed" + ViewData["formId"] + "?page=" + ViewData["pageNumber"];

    }

    var pageViewModel;


    $.ajax({ url: '@startUrl' ,
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            //console.log("JSON received:  " + JSON.stringify(data));            

            // when i bind to the view model the parent question text shows, but not the child answers
            pageViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
            ko.applyBindings(pageViewModel);
            //ko.applyBindings(data);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("Error: TextStatus: " + textStatus + " errorThrown: " + errorThrown);
        }
    });
    </script>
```

And here's some of the data in JSON:

```
 [{"FormId":0,"QuestionId":28807,"QuestionSelectionMode":"StaticTextSelection","QuestionText":"<hr />\r\n<div><span style=\"font-size: medium\"><span style=\"color: #003366\"><strong>Event Details</strong></span></span></div>","DisplayOrder":1,"PageNumber":1,"Answers":[]},{"FormId":0,"QuestionId":28782,"QuestionSelectionMode":"RadioButtonSelection","QuestionText":"<div><span style=\"font-size: larger\"><strong>What type of patient safety event is being reported?</strong></span><span style=\"font-size: x-small\"><strong>&nbsp; </strong><font color=\"#ff0000\" size=\"1\">(Required)</font></span></div>","DisplayOrder":2,"PageNumber":1,"Answers":[{"AnswerId":460935,"QuestionId":0,"AnswerTypeId":null,"RegularExpressionId":null,"AnswerText":"Reached the patient","DisplayOrder":1,"Selected":null,"DefaultText":null,"Mandatory":null,"ValidatorId":null,"SyncRefMandatory":null,"FieldLength":null,"AnswerFormId":null,"EntryMaskId":null,"ShowTimeSelector":null,"Disabled":false},{"AnswerId":460936,"QuestionId":0,"AnswerTypeId":null,"RegularExpressionId":null,"AnswerText":"Did not reach the patient (Near Miss)","DisplayOrder":2,"Selected":null,"DefaultText":null,"Mandatory":null,"ValidatorId":null,"SyncRefMandatory":null,"FieldLength":null,"AnswerFormId":null,"EntryMaskId":null,"ShowTimeSelector":null,"Disabled":false},{"AnswerId":460937,"QuestionId":0,"AnswerTypeId":null,"RegularExpressionId":null,"AnswerText":"Unsafe Condition","DisplayOrder":3,"Selected":null,"DefaultText":null,"Mandatory":null,"ValidatorId":null,"SyncRefMandatory":null,"FieldLength":null,"AnswerFormId":null,"EntryMaskId":null,"ShowTimeSelector":null,"Disabled":false}]},{"FormId":0,"QuestionId":46080,"QuestionSelectionMode":"RadioButtonSelection","QuestionText":"<div><span style=\"font-size: larger\"><strong>Was the patient harmed?</strong></span></div>","DisplayOrder":3,"PageNumber":1,"Answers":[{"AnswerId":632595,"QuestionId":0,"AnswerTypeId":null,"RegularExpressionId":null,"AnswerText":"Yes","DisplayOrder":1,"Selected":null,"DefaultText":null,"Mandatory":null,"ValidatorId":null,"SyncRefMandatory":null,"FieldLength":null,"AnswerFormId":null,"EntryMaskId":null,"ShowTimeSelector":null,"Disabled":false},{"AnswerId":632596,"QuestionId":0,"AnswerTypeId":null,"RegularExpressionId":null,"AnswerText":"No","DisplayOrder":2,"Selected":null,"DefaultText":null,"Mandatory":null,"ValidatorId":null,"SyncRefMandatory":null,"FieldLength":null,"AnswerFormId":null,"EntryMaskId":null,"ShowTimeSelector":null,"Disabled":false}]}, and so on...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What does the data look like?

Comment: Here's a partial dump of the data:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the if binding, you're putting in an entire statement, not just referring to a property on the viewmodel.  Because of this, you need to call the observable (as a function) rather than just refer to it.  Translation: instead of

```
<div data-bind="if: QuestionSelectionMode == 'CheckBoxSelection'">
```

you should have

```
<div data-bind="if: QuestionSelectionMode() == 'CheckBoxSelection'">
```

So here is the updated markup:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: $data">
    <p data-bind="html: QuestionText">

    <!-- RadioButtonSelection-->
    <div data-bind="if: QuestionSelectionMode() == 'RadioButtonSelection'">
        <span data-bind="foreach: Answers">
            <input type="radio" data-bind="attr: {name: $parent.QuestionId}, value: AnswerId" /><span data-bind="text: AnswerText"></span>
        </span>
    </div>

    <!-- CheckBoxSelection-->
    <div data-bind="if: QuestionSelectionMode() == 'CheckBoxSelection'">
     <span data-bind="foreach: Answers">
            <div><input type="checkbox" data-bind="value: AnswerId"/><span data-bind="text: AnswerText"></span></div>
        </span>
    </div>

    <!-- DropDownListSelection-->
    <div data-bind="if: QuestionSelectionMode() == 'DropDownListSelection'">
        <select data-bind="options: Answers, optionsText: 'AnswerText', optionsValue: 'AnswerId'"></select>
    </div>

</div>​
```

And here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g5g36/

A couple of other notes:

1. You're trying to do the 'html:answers' binding on the p tag.  The html binding is designed to tell knockout that you have an HTML string on your viewmodel that you want to go inside an existing tag.  But then you define all kinds of other markup inside the p tag.  Just get rid of this tag completely.
2. I had to correct the JSON so that you had double slashes instead of single slashes (see fiddle) to make the JSON parser happy.  This may not be relevant for you depending on how your service handles things.
3. $data is implicit in a binding, so instead of binding to '$data.Answers', you can just bind to 'Answers'.  Either way works, but removing the $data makes it cleaner.
4. You're not technically supposed to have div tags inside p tags.
5. The p tags are supposed to be closed

Comment: Thanks, CodeThug. Am I right to assume the mapping library is converting all properties to observables by default? Keep thuggin'.

Comment: That is correct.  From the documentation at http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html, all properties are converted into observables, and all arrays are converted into observableArrays.